# Preventing typescript from allowing undefined return

Tags: typescript

I've got all the strict flags that I would expect turned on, so I was confused when Typescript accepted the following code:

```
export class Test {
    private records: {
        [id: string]: number
    };
    constructor() {
        this.records = {
            "hello": 1,
            "world": 3
        }
    }

    public get(id: string): number {
        return this.records[id];
    } 
}
```

The `get` property obviously does *not* always return a number: it will return `undefined` when the function is passed anything besides `"hello"` and `"world"`. Is there a flag that would catch this function and require its return type to be `number | undefined`, which is the correct return type?

I'm using `noImplicitAny` and `strictNullChecks` already. Surely there's some way to do this, as I have a function that claims to return a `number` returning `undefined`!

Comment: Your type says that *any* string key on that object will return a number. If only specific known properties will be accessible, use a more specific type.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - if that was the case, then there should be a type error in the constructor, and there is not. I am aware I could use a more specific interface type in this instance, but the example I took this from had a method `set(id: string, n: number): void` as well.

Comment: Fundamentally, the problem arises because your type for `records` is wrong. As you say, if the key is missing you get undefined, so it should be `[id: string]: number | undefined`. Then you do get the appropriate warnings on the method. I don't know why you think there should be a type error in the constructor. See also this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9235

Comment: @jonrsharpe Rob Simmons has a good point saying that because it is obvious that an object cannot contain every possible key as a number. So, for some keys, it should be undefined.

Comment: @lilezek yes, I understand what they're saying, but that's just not how the index signature works.

Comment: Indeed it is. That is really discouraging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on jonrsharpe's comments, I eventually found [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778). The answer as I understand it is that this type:

```
interface Wha { 
    foo: number;
    bar: number;
    [id: string]: number;
};
```

is *always incorrect*, because the type system treats it like it is an object that maps *every single `id`* to a *defined number*, and no such object can *ever exist*. (Every object that you can possibly create will always have strings that don't map to numbers, as lilezek pointed out in comments.)

Typescript is perfectly happy giving this object the `Wha` type:

```
let r: Wha = { foo: 4, bar: 7, baz: 33 };
```

Because it incorrectly thinks that every `string` index in a `Wha` object maps to a defined `number`, Typescript will treat `r.notafield`, `r.fnord`, and `r["ha"]` as having type `number`. Therefore, it will happily proceed as if all of these things cannot *possibly* be undefined. But they all are `undefined`! Avoiding that situation is why I wanted to use Typescript with `--strictNullChecks` in the first place

If you want to avoid having a bunch of `undefined` things zipping around the typechecker pretending to be a totally-defined `number`, the only option is this:

```
interface Wha { 
    foo: number;
    bar: number;
    [id: string]: number | undefined;
};
```

This leads to all sorts of problems, because it means that you can have valid keys in the array that mapped to undefined, where what you *originally meant* was that, if `k` is a key in `Object.keys(r)`, then `r[k]` is a `number`. So there's no good option here.

Maybe the lesson here is that I should use [ES6 Maps](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4604-L4612) instead of indexable types, because indexable types lie to you without warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
public get(id: string): number | undefined {
    return this.records[id];
}
```

Or this:

```
public get(id: string) {
    return this.records[id] as number | undefined;
}
```

One of these should explicitly return undefined as a possible type.